# How to write foreign characters to a text file in c#?

Tags: c#, file, text, io

So I want to write into a file with foreign characters within the console, But I keep getting the symbol ⍰. And it would print ⍰ to the file, how do I actually write the characters in the file?

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;

namespace DaProgram{
    public class Program{

      static void main(string[] args){ 

         string filePath = @"C:\User\AppData";

         Console.WriteLine("おはようございます");

         string text = Console.Readline();

         File.WriteAllText(filePath, text);

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: maybe the file encoding doesn't match yours? File.WriteAllText(filePath, text, Encoding.UTF8);

Comment: I got the consoles able to display and receive the text, but when I see the file's contents, its still question marks

Comment: I added an answer

Answer (score 0):

if the input data is equal to the output data, then the problem is in your text editor. It may have ASCII encoding by default

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string filePath = @"C:\User\AppData";
    Console.WriteLine("おはようございます");
    string text = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine($"Input text:{text}");
    File.WriteAllText(filePath, text, Encoding.UTF8);
    var readText = File.ReadAllText(filePath, Encoding.UTF8);
    Console.WriteLine($"Read from file:{readText}");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```